# DRUPAL - How can I add user ID (UID) to the activation email oder user page?

Tags: drupal, token

How can I add the value user id (uid) from user db in to the activation email?

like : "hi XY your ID is :1234"

and I would like to print out the id on the user page.

thx

Answer (score 3):

For the E-mails you can do the following:
In drupal admin go to Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings, be sure you are on the settings tab.

if you then scroll to the bottom of the page (seven theme) you find a section named E-mail. 
There you can add:

```
hi [user:name] your ID is :[user:uid]
```

Add this to all e-mail templates the you want the user id in.

And to add this to the profile page you can add the following ing you template.php file:

```
/**
* Process variables for user-profile.tpl.php.
 *
 * The $variables array contains the following arguments:
 * - $account
 *
 * @see user-profile.tpl.php
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['elements']['#account'];

    // Helpful $user_profile variable for templates.
  foreach (element_children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['user_profile'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }

  //this is added to print user id
  $variables['user_profile']['uid']['#type'] = 'user_profile_item';
  $variables['user_profile']['uid']['#title'] = 'User ID';
  $variables['user_profile']['uid']['#markup'] = $account->uid;


  field_attach_preprocess('user', $account, $variables['elements'], $variables);
}
```

cheers, 
Jørgen

Comment: Jorgen i try this with : hi [user:name] your ID is :[user:uid]
 but it das not work! i get the string back "hi [user:name] your ID is :[user:uid]
"

Comment: i add also the lines to my tamplate.php file and under my account the ID is not ther!

i put it on the end of the template.php file from garland themes-->garland-->template.php ist this ok?

thx for helping

Comment: i am using drupal 6.20 ist that importent to know?

Comment: Hi, are you using drupal 6 or 7? For the e-mail, I misled you if you dont have token installed. I'm just so used to always addding some modules that I don't remember how it looks without them. Add token, and you will get a list of tokens to use in your e-mails (http://drupal.org/project/token). When it comes to displaying the id of a user on their profile page I'm using a zen zub-theme, so I'm not familiar with the Garland theme for this. But i guess that adding it at the end as you did should work. You won't get it on the edit screen, bur the view profiel screen.

Comment: and see my edit in the code. If you use garland, change to garland_preprocess....

Comment: ah, ok. I'm on 7, so I can't verify the correctness for 6. But try changing the name to start with garland.

Comment: hi i have token installed! and on the token list page (http://drupal.org/node/390482)   [uid] exist in the list!
i use also a zen subtheme now bu shut i not print the new variabe out that we crate in auer template.php file?

with the email is still not working :-)

Comment: Hi, in my token list for e-mail (remember that it's drupal 7), the token to use is: [user:uid]. You do not have to print your new variable ( at least not in drupal 7 ), because it's handled by print render($user_profile); in the user-profile.tpl.php

Comment: did you test it with [user:uid]? on you own page? I everything wat you say but it still not work^^...dou you have any idee wyh? thx

Comment: yup, I tested it for one type of e-mail messages and it worked. But this is on drupal 7. As you pointed out, on drupal 6 it looks like [uid] is the way to go. Best of luck.

Comment: hmm i enter [uid] in the mail but it doesn't work^^ and dou you have solution for the user page?

Comment: My code works on my Drupal 7 install, so I can't offer you anything better. Could you put your template.php file on pastebin or something?

Comment: sure hier : http://pastebin.com/EDh2AVCg

i get this error now : Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /homepages/14/d345518775/htdocs/poppawid/sites/all/themes/ninesixtyrobots/template.php on line 160

Comment: Hi, I had a look at the api for drupal 6, and it's very different (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/6). You should tag this drupal-6, and you might get some guys that actually can help you. Sorry. But at least you have the code if you ever want to switch to Drupal 7 ;)

Comment: and wat cann you say about the error?on line 160? D7 das not support als modules that i need!

Comment: What modules did not support D7? The error is because you (I) try to access the $variables incorrectly. This is because there is a difference between D7 and D6. So it won't have the same entries in the $variables array. by best tip is skip my code, insert the body of the function in the link in my latest comment and start from there. Try to do print_r($variables); to see if you can find the uid in there somewhere. I can't do it since I'm on D7. Cheers, J

Comment: i make now a list of all modules that i need if hey all supports D7 i will install an make the site in D7..but you are sute that it works with D7?:-) the uid and the user page? lloks like the user core modul ist disabled in D7 dou you user profile2?

Comment: great, at least we're on the same page :D Now, try the above.